# Listbox only displays each character on the textbox

Tags: webforms, listbox

- I am using the listbox to display them on the textbox. But I click button, it displays each character and only displays the first item. Is there any solution?
- Now, I want to click items, it will display on the textbox without clicking the button. And each item is separated by a ",". So how do I do it?
  Thanks so much!

```
protected void btnChon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-R8LG380\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PHIM;Integrated Security=True");
            txtDienVien.Text = "";
            foreach (var DienVienId in lbxDienVien.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                txtDienVien.Text += DienVienId + ", ";
            }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do this in asp.net or winforms as you have both tags.  you're probably looking for the listbox index changed event. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @RandomCoder Sorry, I am trying in webforms

Comment: The wording of this question is making it hard to understand what the actual problem is